# Скрипт не срабатывает или срабатывает несколько раз

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть некий

```
<div id="tovar"></div>
куда вставляются даныые:

echo "<div id='item_".$my_id."'>
<table class='table_1' width='100%'>
<td width='8%;'><center><input class='del_button2' type='text' style='width:25px' id='del2-".$my_id."' value='1'/></center></td>
</table></div>";
```

который рисует таблицу с полем ввода, который нужно изменять. POST запросом отправляется id строки и нужное значение.

```
$(function(){
    $(".del_button2").keydown(function(event) {
    var clickedID = this.id.split("-"); //Разбиваем строку (Split работает аналогично PHP explode)
    var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //и получаем номер из массива
    var log = $("#del2-"+DbNumberID).val();
      if (event.keyCode == '13') {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ser/kvit2.php",
            data: "action=adduser&log="+log+"&stroka="+DbNumberID,
            success: function(html){
                $("#logff").html(html);            
            }
            });
       }
    });
});
```

Так вот, если сначала вызвать javascript код, а потом форму с таблицей (с помощью добавления данных без перезагрузки страницы), то сприпт вообще не понимает, что на странице появилась новая таблица.

А если таблицу с данными выводить вместе с подгрузкой яваскрипта, то при добавлении нескольких таблиц также несколько раз подгружается javascript, и на первых таблицах скрипт начинает выполнять столько POST запросов, сколько таблиц и было добавлено. Как от этого избавиться?

Comment: Исправил код следующим образом:

    $("body").on("keydown", "#tovar .del_button2", function(e) {
    var clickedID = this.id.split("-");
    var DbNumberID = clickedID[1];
    var log = $("#del2-"+DbNumberID).val();
    if (e.keyCode == '13') {

     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "ser/kvit2.php",
     data: "action=adduser&log="+log+"&stroka="+DbNumberID,
      success: function(html){
       $("#logff").html(html);            
         }
        });
     }
});

т.к. метод "on" позволяет вызывать обработчик ДО загрузки данных. Теперь все работает как нужно :)

Answer (score 1):

Мне трудно понять, что именно скрипт делает и что именно Вы хотите.

1. JS прослушивает все элементы **с классом** `del_button2` на событие  keydown.
2. При event.keyCode == '13' выполняется Post запрос.

Можно к input добавить onsubmit.

```
<input class='del_button2' id='del2-".$my_id."' onsubmit='ajaxPost(this)'/>
```

В js прописать функцию, которая будет работать с определённым полем, а не со всеми сразу.

```
function ajaxPost(delButton){  
// Эта функция будет вызвана при нажатии Enter внутри текстового поля  
}
```

Comment: JS прослушивает все элементы с классом del_button2 на событие keydown.
При event.keyCode == '13' выполняется Post запрос

Это все правильно, это и требуется. Все работает. НО до тех пор, пока в   <div id="tovar"></div> не прилетит новая таблица, которая описана в ECHO выше. В таком случае, JS уже не видит новую таблицу (до тех пор, пока не перезагрузить страницу). А необходимо, чтобы JS понимал и новую поступившую таблицу (которая вошла в этот DIV без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: JS всё видит, просто на новую таблицу не присвоен обработчик. Ведь обработчик присваивается при загрузке страницы. А при загрузке страницы новых данных не было. Попробуйте через onsubmit.